# Securing the Realm Object Server with Let’s Encrypt

Tags: java, ssl, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-object-server

I do instructions of [Securing the Realm Object Server with Let’s Encrypt](http://news.realm.io/news/securing-the-realm-object-server-with-lets-encrypt/) step by step and thanks for good article of [Nikola Irinchev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1649102/nikola-irinchev) that's work so good. When i want to use realms:// instead of realm:// and read [docs of Realm Java 3.4.0](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#ssltls) for using SSL/TLS:

```
SyncConfiguration syncConfiguration = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(user, "realms://host/~/myapp")
            .serverCertificate("root_ca.pem")
            .build();
```

that's not correct because serverCertificate() function not available and i suggest correct is:

```
SyncConfiguration syncConfiguration = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(user, "realms://host/~/myapp")
            .trustedRootCA("root_ca.pem")
            .build();
```

but after user login, realm not synced and Realm file was created in ROS can't be opened. My question is what pem file i should use in android app?

I use fullchain.pem and depart it to cert.pem and chain.pem and use all of them but my problem not resolved. Please guide me.

Comment: I use .disableSSLVerification() and my Realm is synced but can't open realm file with realm browser and my question is still what pem file need to be used

Comment: After one day and some transaction realm file has opened with realm browser

Comment: My sync app in debug mode work properly with good speed

Comment: I will test release app with 3 option that available and share result of my test as soon as posible

Comment: Hello @saeed, where did you find the right certificate? :)